# How to reduce size of jenkins agent image

Tags: jenkins

over the months I'v been adding new packages to docker jenkins agent image - that is used in GKE, and atm its size is over 5GB, having cloud sdk, all kubernetes/helm/docker dependencies gradle and some other custom binaries required - any suggestions on how some of you trim yours or do you allow it to escalate to this size?

I was thinking of removing gradle for e.g, as only 2 jobs use it and move step that gets it into pre-job-steps to download it and setup, as 99% of other jobs dont need to use it and extra 600MB for each job can add to quite a bit.

So do you have multiple jenkins-agent images or just one monolith?

Answer (score 1):

If your main purpose is to reduce image size, then:

1. use alpine images
2. use .dockerignore file
3. Use multi-stage builds
4. Install needed tools on the run and use --no-cache option `RUN apk add --no-cache git`
5. Separate image to several small ones
6. Remove unnecessary tools
7. Clean package manager folder `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` or `rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`

Suppose I didn't miss anything.

Comment: yup, was already doing the step 4 and 7, as suggested in dockerfile linters, as per 5th, im  not sure if you can have specific jenkins agent image for specific jobs and will have to look at multi-stage builds, not sure how they behave when I just copy over 5 binaries each 0.5GB big

Comment: im not sure if you can have specific jenkins agent image for specific jobs - yes you can have as much images as you want, you can even call different agent images in different pipeline steps.